# Remove part of a string inside a tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I have a page with links that look like this:

`<a class="title" href="#">Recipes using <b>veal</b> - My Recipes</a>`

I want to remove all the "- My Recipes" from these links, leaving (in this case):

`Recipes using <b>veal</b>`

I have tried many variations on `$('a.title').replace( "- My Recipes", "" );`

I think I must be targeting it wrong.

Comment: Do you also assign the return value...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
$('a.title').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace( "- My Recipes", "" ));
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxbDK/)

Comment: Thanks.  So I need to use this.html twice for things like this?

Comment: yes or you can do like Kevin B and use `.html(function(i,html)` then the html var is like $(this).html()

Answer (score 1):

The .html method can handle it:

```
$('a.title').html(function ( i, html ) {
    return html.replace( "- My Recipes", "" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QxbDK/2/

Probably better though to instead change what's returning this content so that it isn't there to begin with.